# Show numpy stack of frames in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a numpy stack with shape (1,64,96,4) where (64,96) are the pixels that correspond to an image captured from the screen (frame) and 4 is the number of frames stacked. So basically the stack has 4 2d arrays(64,96). This stack is used as an input to a Deep q network.

I want to display with matplotlib the different frames but I have not managed to access the correct elements.

Here's the code for creating the stack of frames:

```
frame = self.preprocess_frame(frame)  # (64,96)
state = np.stack([frame] * 4, axis=-1)
state = state.reshape(1, state.shape[0], state.shape[1], state.shape[2])  # 1*64*96*4, the extra dimension is only used for Keras library

return state
```

The problem is how to access the different frames from the stack , so to feed them in `matplotlib.imshow`

I have tried this to get just one frame but it did not work out :

```
plt.imshow(state[1], state[2])
plt.show()
```

Thank you in advance !!!

Comment: Hi, since `state` is numpy array with dimensions `(1, 64, 96, 4)`, you should be able to access the four frames using `state[0][..., i]` or `state[..., i][0]` where i = 0, 1, 2, 3. Each of these will return one `(64, 96)` array

Comment: Thanks it works like it should.